# Simple tabs with content scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use universal jqueryUI tabs with [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) and it only works on the first tab, pls help me  fix this code - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ATTimi/3Ayy7/9/)
This Code

```
 (function($) {
   $(function() {
     $('ul.tabs').delegate('li:not(.current)', 'click', function() {
       $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current')
         .parents('div.section').eq(0).find('>div.box').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
     })

   })
  })(jQuery);   
  (function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
           $('.scroller').mCustomScrollbar({
        autoHideScrollbar:true
                });
            });
   })(jQuery);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're only adding a scroller on `$(window).load`. You need to make add functionality to compensate for changing tabs as well, like this:

```
(function($){
    $('.tabs').click(function() {
        $('.scroller').mCustomScrollbar("destroy");
        $('.scroller').mCustomScrollbar({
            autoHideScrollbar:true
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ayy7/10/)